# list_item and single_list_item containing different XML tags (RSS)

Tags: java, android, listview, rss, xml-parsing

I'm using RSS with different tags for my app and I want to show, for example, `<title>` and `<pubDate>` in my List, but when I click on specific item it suppose to open new layout which contains `<title>` and `<description>`.

I would appreciate any kind of help, link, hint or whatever :)

Thanks

Comment: I've tried using ListAdapter but the only thing i knew to do was to put same tags (for example title and date) both on list_item and single_list_item.

Answer (score 0):

ListViews are tricker. The ListAdapter you use has to specify a layout that describes a single entry in the list, the source data items, and for each item the destination View in the single entry layout. There has to be a one-to-one correspondence between source item and destination View. HOWEVER, the array/Cursor/whatever that *contains* the source data can have more data in it. For a SimpleCursorAdapter, for instance, the Cursor itself can contain 15 items, but you only have to show 2. For a SimpleCursorAdapter, source items are specified as column names in an array of String, and destination Views are specified as resourceIDs in an array of int.

The most friendly way to display the details of a single list entry is to have an onClickListener that opens a new Activity/Fragment when clicked. The Listener is passed the index of the entry that was clicked. From this, you can work back to the Cursor row that backs that entry, then pass the necessary data to the new Activity/Fragment.

I used Cursor because that's the most common use case, but the same pattern works for arrays, lists, etc.